# Did namespace change of WCF used class could cause problems?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, service

Did change of class namespace which is used in *WCF Service* as *parameter* or *return value* could cause problems on client side?

I mean C# namespace, **not** WSDL namespace.

Comment: It depends on how your service is being consumed, can you give a few more details, also have you tried anything and found it to fail?

Comment: I did not try anything. I found out that namespace name exist in WSDL, so I wonder there could be some reference to that on client side. Service will be consumed using BasicHttpBinding

Comment: Try consuming the service and let us know how it goes.

Comment: In most cases, you may have to regenerate your client reference, if you use the service reference feature.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some code as an example of what you have done. What does your `.svc` file contain, what are the operation and data contracts?

Answer (score 0):

I add this in my WCF project above the namespace:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://WCF/WebService/", ClrNamespace = "someNamespace")] 
namespace someNamespace
{
}
```

So, when I want to change the namespace in WCF, I only change the C# namespace *someNamespace* and the  WSDL and the proxys will keep the namespace

> WCF.WebService

Answer (score 0):

For typical web service this is not a problem, since WSDL/SOAP do not take their namespaces from c# namespaces. If you use binary serizlization or other .net specific setting watch out since WCF may include CLR types/namespaces in the XML.